# How to replace text with insert new text with floating text or any for not disturb pdf format?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, text, pymupdf

problem :

The problem I am currently experiencing is that I want to replace text that already exists in a PDF file, but the output from my program corrupts the PDF file format. One example is loss of profits. Do you know the solution to my problem?

problem output :

[image: that's my problem, my inserted text was disturb pdf format]

the code :

```
doc = fitz.open(GMS_FILE_FORMAT)
search_term = '@period'
replace_term = '120 hari'

for page in doc:
    found = page.search_for(search_term)
    for item in found:
         page.add_redact_annot(item, '')
         page.apply_redactions()
         page.insert_text(item.bl - (0, 3), replace_term)
```

Comment: You are using PyMuPDF and redaction annotations to do the replacement. You are doing it in two steps: (1) erase old text, (2) insert new text. Which is perfectly ok. Maybe your page has non-wrapped coordinate system changes, such that your insertion lands in the wrong place. Try to do this: (1) do not specify **any** new text in the making of the redaction (no "" there), (2) execute `page.clean_contents()` right after page loading. This will wrap coordinate system changes.